# What are temporary folders/files of VSCode that can be safely deleted without affecting VSCode's correct performance?

Tags: linux, windows, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I look at the `%tmp%` folder in Windows and I notice that there are some VSCode related files/folders there. It is [well understood](https://www.pcworld.com/article/2602104/how-to-clean-your-windows-temp-folder.html) that files/folders in `%tmp%` can be safely deleted. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pmI-rgGNZcs) video seems to suggest that cached files/folders in `C:\Users\Tryer\AppData\Roaming\Code`, more specifically in `Cache` and `CachedData` folders can be safely deleted. There are other similar *sounding* folders there `CachedConfigurations`, `CachedExtensions`, `CachedExtensionsVSIXs`, `Code Cache`, `CrashPad`, `GPUCache`, etc.

Is there a complete list of files and folders that can be safely deleted without affecting VSCode's performance and correctness and behavior ? What I mean is that these files and folders should be safe to delete without affecting the behavior of the extensions that one has loaded and the behavior of VSCode itself.

Also, what are the equivalent files/folders' locations that are safe to delete in `linux` systems and `WSL` systems?

Comment: Did you ever find out?

Comment: @myke Not really. I posted in multiple places for VSCode as well as Visual Studio IDE. But this does not seem to be on their priority list.